# Mergesort with $O(n^2 \log n)$ runtime

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I have a task where i need to find a problem in which mergesort has to have a runtime of $O(n^2 \log n)$. In our lecture we said that the runtime is $O(n \log n)$ assuming that every comparison is $O(1)$. I think that I have to work with comparison-complexity but I dont know how to create a runtime of $O(n^2 \log n)$ since mergesort has best and worst-case complexity of $O(n \log n)$. Could anybody help me out creating a problem to achieve a runtime of $O(n^2 \log n)$ ?

Comment: Hint: try to think of your input as not being necessarily a set of atomic objects.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos so you mean if i take for instance vectors except of numbers than it will work ?

Comment: That would be a start.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos thank you i did not think of this option ! i think that will help me a lot :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember what $O(\cdot)$ means. You don't need to do anything. Mergesort has a running time of $O(n\log n)$ which is already $O(n^2 \log n)$, $O(2^n)$ and $O(\text{any larger function you want})$.

Comment: what is O(⋅) specifically ? i see this notation for the first time (i want to google it)

Comment: Oh lol. Sorry but I thought the "dot" has a meaning.

Comment: Oh! It just stands for "something". :-)